# not able to get json passed into intent to another activity

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, bundle

I am using below code(in brief)

In Global class named as Utilities
public static final String KEY = "MY_KEY";

```
//Pojo Class    
ViewPojo mPojo;   

//ActivityDemo    
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);    
intent.putExtra(Utilities.KEY, new Gson().toJson(mPojo));

//MyActivity    
pojoJson = getIntent().getStringExtra(Utilities.KEY);     
mPojo = new Gson().fromJson(pojoJson, ViewPojo.class);
```

null is being returned, I am not clear how and why this is happening.
same is working in case of Bundle.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why JSON you can simply pass your POJO object using serializable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the `stringExtra` from the intent you should get the extra's from the intent and form there get the string.

```
//MyActivity
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
pojoJson = extras.getString(Utilities.KEY);     
mPojo = new Gson().fromJson(pojoJson, ViewPojo.class);
```

You could also use a Parcelable implementation to directly send the object through the intent instead of parsing it to JSON, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html for more information

Comment: I have also used by getting Bundle from Intent and then get the string from the retrieved Bundle, but that's returning null. However, If am using string as "MY_KEY" to put and get parsed json its working fine but the is not working if I am using String constant like static final String key = "MY_KEY" or static String key = "MY_KEY".

Answer (score 0):

Please specify null value return intent.

so use bundle

Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
mPojo = new Gson().fromJson(extras.getString(Utilities.KEY), ViewPojo.class);

Comment: what would be difference in this case also idea is same like getting a parsed json from bundle that was passed into the intent.